# Flow Router SSR parameter error

Tags: meteor, flow-router

I would like to get url parameter with my **SSR** Flow Router

```
FlowRouter.route("/:lang", {
  name: "home",
  action({lang}) {
    console.log(lang);
    mount(MainLayout, {
      content: () => (<Home/>)
    });
  }
});
```

I don't know why, but I'm getting this error on route `http://localhost:3000/testparam`

`Error when doing SSR. path:/testparam: Expected "lang" to be defined`

My console.log with "testparam" appears **before** error on server side console.

Edit:
On **client** side the error also appears:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Expected "lang" to be defined
```

Comment: Does it also happen without SSR?

Answer (score 0):

I think the {lang} is not correct. Try

`action(params) { console.log(params.lang) }`

here an example of my demo which uses the SSR Router:

https://github.com/LucaMele/meteor-react-ssr-app-demo/blob/master/lib/routing.js